# django 2: Filter models by every day of current month

Tags: django, django-models

I got a simple models like this:

```
class CurrentMonthRegisterPage(models.Manager):
    """This manager class filter with current month."""
    current_date = datetime.now().date()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(CurrentMonthRegisterPage, self).get_queryset().filter(
            detail_hour__month=self.current_date.month, detail_hour__year=self.current_date.year)

class RegisterPage(models.Model):
    OTHERS = '4'  
    EXTRA_TIME = '3'  
    EARLIER = '2'  
    ON_TIME = '1'  
    LATE = '0'  

    ABSENT = '-'  

    STATUS_LIST = (
        (LATE, _("Late")),
        (ON_TIME, _("On time")),
        (EARLIER, _("Earlier")),
        (EXTRA_TIME, _("Extra time")),
        (OTHERS, _("ND")),
        (ABSENT, _("Absent")),
    )
    detail_hour = models.DateTimeField(_('Date and hour'), auto_now_add=True)

    details_mouvement = models.TextField(_("Déscription"), blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(_("Statut"), max_length=1, choices=STATUS_LIST, default=ABSENT)
    objects = RecentManager()
    c_month = CurrentMonthRegisterPage()
```

*Now i want to get a number of every state of every day of current month*

Example:

Current month is March

How to get a number of **state==LATE** of **every day** of **march** ?

**I want to get something like this:**

```
queryset = [{'late':[1,1,3,5,....31], 'other_state': [1,2,...], ...}]
```

Please help ?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Look March month have 31 days, I want to get number of every state of every day of march.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a query with fields for day and state, then you do a count (implicitly grouping by day and state):

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc

queryset = (RegisterPage.c_month
    .annotate(day=Trunc('detail_hour', 'day'))
    .values('day', 'state')
    .annotate(count=Count('day'))
    .order_by('day', 'state')
)
```

I've added an ordering clause to remove any existing ordering (that would thwart the desired grouping) and to sort the results.

The results only include days and states that are actually present in the data, if you want to include missing days or states with the count `0`, you may want to do it in Python code.

Comment: Yes want to include missing days or states with the count 0 how can i do it in python code ?